# Count using xslt when looking at sub-strings

Tags: templates, xslt, xpath, count, substring

I would like to count the number of items that match the following conditions:

```
/results/errors/error/[@severity='warning']
```

and

```
test="not(string-length(substring-before(/results/errors/error/location/@file,'cow'))=0)"
```

So, while my first condition can easily be counted by using the built in count function
    count(//results/errors/error[@severity='warning'])

I do not know how to use the count function for the second condition, as it is not in Xpath format.

Any help you can provide to me would be greatly appreciated.  (My XML is below)

The desired answer would be: 2

Thank you,
Belinda

My xml looks like this:

```
<results version="2">
    <errors>
        <error id="redundantAssignment" severity="performance" msg="blah, blah.">
            <location file="/farm/user/cow/src/IO/file1.cpp"/>
            <location file="/farm/user/horse//src/IO/file5.cpp"/>
        </error>
        <error id="redundantAssignment" severity="warning" msg="blah, blah.">
            <location file="/farm/user/sheep/src/IO/file1.cpp"/>
            <location file="/farm/user/cow/src/IO/file2.cpp"/>
        </error>
        <error id="redundantAssignment" severity="error" msg="blah, blah.">
            <location file="/farm/user/horse/src/IO/file1.cpp"/>
            <location file="/farm/user/cow//src/IO/file3.cpp"/>
        </error>
        <error id="redundantAssignment" severity="warning" msg="blah, blah.">
            <location file="/farm/user/sheep/src/IO/file1.cpp"/>
            <location file="/farm/user/cow/src/IO/file3.cpp"/>
        </error>
        <error id="redundantAssignment" severity="warning" msg="blah, blah.">
            <location file="/farm/user/sheep/src/IO/file1.cpp"/>
            <location file="/farm/user/horse/src/IO/file3.cpp"/>
        </error>
        <error id="redundantAssignment" severity="style" msg="blah, blah.">
            <location file="/farm/user/sheep/src/IO/file1.cpp"/>
            <location file="/farm/user/horse/src/IO/file4.cpp"/>
        </error>
        <error id="redundantAssignment" severity="style" msg="blah, blah.">
            <location file="/farm/user/sheep/src/IO/file1.cpp"/>
            <location file="/farm/user/horse/src/IO/file2.cpp"/>
        </error>
    </errors>
</results>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to combine both into a single `count()` by adding the second test to the first predicate:

```
count(/results/errors/error[@severity='warning' and location[not(string-length(substring-before(@file,'cow'))=0)]])
```

Using your sample XML input, this produces `2`.

Simplification using `contains()` suggested by Tim C...

```
count(/results/errors/error[@severity='warning' and location[contains(@file,'cow')]])
```

Comment: I believe the test on location can actually be simplified by using **contains**. `location[contains(@file,'cow')]`

Comment: Thank you very, very much for you input.  This was extremely helpful to me.  I just did not know how to do the syntax.

Comment: @Belinda - You're very welcome. Be sure to look at Tim C's comment as well. If this answer is sufficient, please accept it by clicking the check mark to the left of it. Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel Thank you for 1. the original solution, 2. Instruction on how to turn the check mark green (I'm new to posting questions).  Next, how do I officially accept the clean simplification that TimC offered to me?

Comment: @Belinda - I'll edit my question with Tim's suggestion. Otherwise, if Tim had posted his suggestion as an answer, you could accept his instead. If he does post it as an answer, please feel free to accept his instead.